# Unity2D поворот спрайта вместе с персонажем

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity3d

У меня есть персонаж в иерархии, и к нему привязаны все его части тела, и оружие тоже, чтобы оно постоянно было закреплено на уровне тела. Но у меня в коде усмотрено чтобы модель персонажа поворачивалась влево и вправо, но вместе с этим поворачивается и оружие, как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 if (!facingRight && moveInput.x < 0)
            {
                Flip();
            }
            else if (facingRight && moveInput.x > 0)
            {
                Flip();
            }
    private void Flip()
        {
            facingRight = !facingRight;
            Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
            Scaler.x *= -1;
            transform.localScale = Scaler;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у тебя должна быть иерархия:

```
Пустой обьект - Player

    | --- тело плеера
    | --- оружие
```

ести ты повернешь тело плеера, оружие останется без поворота.

И кода писать не нужно вообще.

Comment: Немного не понял. Мне сделать полностью пустой объект? А куда мне кидать все Коллайдеры и Rigidbody2D? Если вы о том чтобы просто сделать пустой объект, под него кинуть тело, и под него оружие, то оружие все еще будет просто висеть в воздухе а не крепиться к телу.

Comment: Я уже пытался делать так как вы описали, если я все правильно понял. Но оружие просто весит в воздухе когда двигается персонаж

Comment: коллайдеры персонажа и риджитбади на пустом обьекте. Тело плеера поворачиваешь - и это ни на что не влияет, только визуальная часть тела поворачивается. Оружие же остается на месте.

Comment: Еще раз извинюсь, но ты меня похоже не правильно понимаешь. Я сделал пустой объект, кинул под него персонажа, и оружие кинул именно под пустой объект, и когда я двигаюсь персонажем, оружие просто весит в воздухе, а мне нужно чтобы оно было прикреплено к телу. https://wdfiles.ru/53e1fe

Comment: логику движения навесь на Player. Логику поворота туловищем тоже в плеер - но поворачивай только обьект туловища внутри плеера. Фактически повернется лишь спрайт туловища.

Comment: А персонаж миленький)

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас попробую через пару минут, благодарю)

Comment: Все, благодарю Вас, все получилось. Просто сделал отдельный скрипт для поворота персонажа и все) Хорошего дня!